# Shinyapps deployment error: Application depends on package "dplyr" but it is not installed

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny

I have an RShiny app consisting of files `ui.R`, `server.R`, and data file `dataFile.RDS` in a folder named as `oliver`. The app is working as expected on my local but when I try to publish it on my shinyapps server it gives me an error saying that `dplyr` package is not installed. The very first line in my script is `install.packages("dplyr")` followed by `library(dplyr)` even then why is it complaining? Any leads please. Complete error log is below:

```
----- Deployment log started at  2021-07-28 22:58:25  -----
Deploy command: 
 rsconnect::deployApp(appDir = "D:/Resume/2021/oliver test/rshiny-exercise/oliver",      appFileManifest = "C:/Users/vipin/AppData/Local/Temp/d00e-70ef-f5fb-f575",      account = "vipin8169", server = "shinyapps.io", appName = "oliver",      appTitle = "oliver", launch.browser = function(url) {         message("Deployment completed: ", url)     }, lint = FALSE, metadata = list(asMultiple = FALSE, asStatic = FALSE),      logLevel = "verbose") 

Session information: 
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.0   rsconnect_0.8.18
Cookies: 
[1] "None"
GET /v1/applications/?filter=account_id:84815&filter=name:oliver&count=100&offset=0 2450ms
----- Bundle upload started at  2021-07-28 22:58:28  -----
[2021-07-28 22:58:28] Inferring App mode and parameters 
[2021-07-28 22:58:28] Bundling app dir 
[2021-07-28 22:58:28] Generate manifest.json 
[2021-07-28 22:58:28] Starting to perform packrat snapshot 

Adding these packages to packrat:
                 _         
    BH             1.75.0-0
    MASS           7.3-51.4
    Matrix         1.2-17  
    R6             2.5.0   
    RColorBrewer   1.1-2   
    Rcpp           1.0.6   
    askpass        1.1     
    base64enc      0.1-3   
    brio           1.1.1   
    bslib          0.2.4   
    cachem         1.0.1   
    callr          3.7.0   
    cli            2.5.0   
    colorspace     2.0-0   
    commonmark     1.7     
    cpp11          0.2.6   
    crayon         1.4.0   
    crosstalk      1.1.1   
    curl           4.3     
    data.table     1.13.6  
    desc           1.3.0   
    diffobj        0.3.3   
    digest         0.6.27  
    dplyr          1.0.7   
    ellipsis       0.3.2   
    evaluate       0.14    
    fansi          0.4.2   
    farver         2.0.3   
    fastmap        1.1.0   
    fs             1.5.0   
    generics       0.1.0   
    ggplot2        3.3.5   
    glue           1.4.2   
    gtable         0.3.0   
    htmltools      0.5.1.1 
    htmlwidgets    1.5.3   
    httpuv         1.5.5   
    httr           1.4.2   
    isoband        0.2.3   
    jquerylib      0.1.3   
    jsonlite       1.7.2   
    labeling       0.4.2   
    later          1.1.0.1 
    lattice        0.20-38 
    lazyeval       0.2.2   
    lifecycle      1.0.0   
    magrittr       2.0.1   
    mgcv           1.8-28  
    mime           0.9     
    munsell        0.5.0   
    nlme           3.1-139 
    openssl        1.4.4   
    pillar         1.6.1   
    pkgconfig      2.0.3   
    pkgload        1.2.1   
    plotly         4.9.4.1 
    praise         1.0.0   
    processx       3.5.2   
    promises       1.1.1   
    ps             1.5.0   
    purrr          0.3.4   
    rappdirs       0.3.3   
    rematch2       2.1.2   
    rlang          0.4.10  
    rprojroot      2.0.2   
    rstudioapi     0.13    
    sass           0.3.1   
    scales         1.1.1   
    shiny          1.6.0   
    sourcetools    0.1.7   
    sys            3.4     
    testthat       3.0.2   
    tibble         3.0.6   
    tidyr          1.1.2   
    tidyselect     1.1.0   
    utf8           1.1.4   
    vctrs          0.3.8   
    viridisLite    0.3.0   
    waldo          0.2.5   
    withr          2.4.1   
    xtable         1.8-4   
    yaml           2.2.1   

[2021-07-28 22:58:31] Completed performing packrat snapshot 
----- Deployment error -----
Error: 
* Application depends on package "dplyr" but it is not installed.
   Please resolve before continuing.
 
----- Error stack trace -----
6: stop(paste(formatUL(errorMessages, "\n*"), collapse = "\n"), 
       call. = FALSE)
5: createAppManifest(appDir = bundleDir, appMode = appMode, contentCategory = contentCategory, 
       hasParameters = hasParameters, appPrimaryDoc = appPrimaryDoc, 
       assetTypeName = assetTypeName, users = users, condaMode = condaMode, 
       forceGenerate = forceGenerate, python = python, hasPythonRmd = hasPythonRmd, 
       retainPackratDirectory = TRUE, verbose = verbose)
4: bundleApp(target$appName, appDir, appFiles, appPrimaryDoc, assetTypeName, 
       contentCategory, verbose, python, condaMode, forceGeneratePythonEnvironment)
3: force(code)
2: withStatus(paste0("Uploading bundle for ", assetTypeName, ": ", 
       application$id), {
       python <- getPythonForTarget(python, accountDetails)
       bundlePath <- bundleApp(target$appName, appDir, appFiles, 
           appPrimaryDoc, assetTypeName, contentCategory, verbose, 
           python, condaMode, forceGeneratePythonEnvironment)
       if (isShinyapps(accountDetails$server)) {
           bundleSize <- file.info(bundlePath)$size
           checksum <- fileMD5.as.string(bundlePath)
           bundle <- client$createBundle(application$id, "application/x-tar", 
               bundleSize, checksum)
           if (verbose) 
               timestampedLog("Starting upload now")
           if (!uploadBundle(bundle, bundleSize, bundlePath)) {
               stop("Could not upload file.")
           }
           if (verbose) 
               timestampedLog("Upload complete")
           response <- client$updateBundleStatus(bundle$id, status = "ready")
           bundle <- client$getBundle(bundle$id)
       }
       else {
           bundle <- client$uploadApplication(application$id, bundlePath)
       }
   })
1: rsconnect::deployApp(appDir = "D:/Resume/2021/oliver test/rshiny-exercise/oliver", 
       appFileManifest = "C:/Users/vipin/AppData/Local/Temp/d00e-70ef-f5fb-f575", 
       account = "vipin8169", server = "shinyapps.io", appName = "oliver", 
       appTitle = "oliver", launch.browser = function(url) {
           message("Deployment completed: ", url)
       }, lint = FALSE, metadata = list(asMultiple = FALSE, asStatic = FALSE), 
       logLevel = "verbose")
Error: 
* Application depends on package "dplyr" but it is not installed.
   Please resolve before continuing.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  Failed to infer source for package 'dplyr'; using latest available version on CRAN instead
2: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  Failed to infer source for package 'dplyr'; using latest available version on CRAN instead
3: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  Failed to infer source for package 'dplyr'; using latest available version on CRAN instead
4: Unable to package DESCRIPTION files: Couldn't find DESCRIPTION file for dplyr 
Execution halted
```

Comment: Your application code should NOT include `install.packages()`. See https://docs.rstudio.com/shinyapps.io/getting-started.html#using-your-r-packages-in-the-cloud. The use of `library()` is sufficient. The package usage will be autodetected.

Comment: Then why is it not detecting `dplyr`, I added the install line only after I got this error.

Comment: I am using the publish option available next to "run app" in the RStudio. I uninstalled R, Rstudio, RTools, and freshly downloaded and installed R and Rstudio and it worked. Clear install worked dunno why.